# Add multiple images to primefaces tab header

Tags: primefaces

I migrated from Icefaces to Primefaces 5.3.5 these lines. They set images to tabs.

```
                <f:facet name="label">
                    <ice:panelGrid columns="2">
                        <ice:graphicImage url="#{currentTab.icon}" title="#{currentTab.title}" height="18" width="18" />
                    </ice:panelGrid>
                </f:facet>
```

in Primefaces

```
<p:tab label=" " styleClass="mainTreeFavoriteTab">

                    <f:facet name="label">
                        <p:panelGrid columns="2">
                            <!-- url of icon is ok -->
                            <p:graphicImage url="#{currentTab.icon}" title="#{currentTab.title}" height="16" width="16" />
                        </p:panelGrid>
                    </f:facet>
```

However, I see that there are no images rendered, only empty tabs.
Can you advise me, please? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be no attribute `label` for p:tab in PF 5.3. Does your IDE accept that? See the user guide [p. 479](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/guide/primefaces_user_guide_5_3.pdf#page=479).

I'm guessing you are looking for `title` facet:

```
<f:facet name="title">
    <p:panelGrid columns="2">
        <!-- url of icon is ok -->
        <p:graphicImage url="#{currentTab.icon}" title="#{currentTab.title}" height="16" width="16" />
    </p:panelGrid>
 </f:facet>
```

and remove `label=" "` on the p:tab.

Comment: I tried also header but it was the same. I think that it does not depend on the name of facet.

Comment: And if you put text inside the facet? Works for me